# Is a C# list like a C++ list?

Tags: c#, c++, list, pointers, vector

Im just wondering if a C# List is like a C++ List.

Removing an element in the middle of a big list in C++ is fast because i know the elements are just pointing to the next.

So when removing a element in the middle of a big C# list, is that the same as in C++? Or is the C# list more like a C++ vector with indexes because you can get the index number of the elements in the C# list.

Comment: AFAIK, the c++ `vector` have indexes.

Comment: No, a LinkedList<> is the same as an std::list.  List<> is the same as std::vector.

Comment: @segfolt Right, but the question doesn't claim otherwise, so I am having trouble understanding the point of your comment. Did it refer to someone else's now-deleted comment?

Comment: @hvd: No. That's because from " the C# list more like a C++ vector **with indexes**" it can be understood that the c++ `vector` doesn't have indexes. Or perhaps I just misunderstood the sentence...

Comment: @segfolt Ah, thanks for clarifying. I read it more like "Or is the C# list more like a C++ vector (i.e. with indexes)"

Comment: Ahh yes, sorry for my unclear question. I meant that because C++ vector has indexes, i believe that C# list is like a C++ vector, becasue it HAS indexes too :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

- C# `List<T>` is analogous to, and has the same performance characteristics, as  C++ `vector<T>`.
- C# `LinkedList<T>` is analagous to, and has the same performance characteristics, as C++ `list<T>`.

The performance characteristics are discussed in some detail in the remarks sections of the relevant sections of the .net documentation: [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), [`LinkedList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx).