# Find on list of map

Tags: c++, hashmap

Hello I'm working on a project and I'm a beginner in C++

I have a list of map

```
list<map<int,double>> voisin;
```

And I would like to know if it's possible to check if the element is present in my map.
This is a C# code and could you tell me how to do it in C++ please.

```
var res = voisin[a].Find(Map<int, double> x)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/

This should clear things up.

```
// map::find
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main ()
{
  std::map<char,int> mymap;
  std::map<char,int>::iterator it;

  mymap['a']=50;
  mymap['b']=100;
  mymap['c']=150;
  mymap['d']=200;

  it=mymap.find('b');
  mymap.erase (it);
  mymap.erase (mymap.find('d'));

  // print content:
  std::cout << "elements in mymap:" << '\n';
  std::cout << "a => " << mymap.find('a')->second << '\n';
  std::cout << "c => " << mymap.find('c')->second << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Output:
    elements in mymap:
    a => 50
    c => 150

Answer (score 0):

Use [`std::map::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/):

```
std::map<int,double>::iterator it = m.find(e);
```

Where `m` is the `map` and `e` is of the same type as the keys in `m`.

`find` returns an iterator to `map::end` if it doesn't find the specified key.

**Note** that [`std::list` in C++ is not the same as `List` in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17013945/3425536). [`std::list`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) is a *linked list*. Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) if you want a container that's equivalent to the C# `List`.